# Использую подмену контента по UTM-меткам на сайте Wordpress. Скрипт не работает на эл-ты header и footer

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Требуется заменить ссылки на сайте Wordpress при наличии определённой utm-метки. Скрипт использую вот этот: https://github.com/1jamagency/contentreplacer/blob/master/contentReplacer.js
Подключил через functions.php темы:

```
    `wp_enqueue_script('change-data-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/change-data.js', array(), false, true);`
```

Если подключаю его в футер, то он работает, контент меняется, но только в пределах основного содержания страницы (кроме элементов footer и header). Если подключаю в хедере (то есть прописываю "array(), false, false"), то он не работает вообще. Мне нужно изменить ссылки в header. В чём может быть проблема?